# applying function to permutated objects

Tags: r, function, permutation

I have, say, 20 objects. I have a function that performs pairwise analyses. I want to do a pairwise analysis on all pairs. Let's say the function is cor.test. Rather than write out all 190 pairs

```
a <- cor.test(1,2);
b <- cor.test(1,3);
c <- cor.test(1,4)
...
```

how can I apply this function to all pairs at once and spit out, in this case, the correlations between each pair? Any advice would be appreciated.

(In case it's important, each object is a matrix)

Comment: I vote to close this question since it is unclear what you are asking. And also you don't provide a reproducible example with the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `combn`, Not clear how you will do your correlations between matrices, but here How I would do this assuming that you have vectors:

```
## put your objects within the same list , you can use `mget` if you have 
## some pattern for your objects names
ll <- list(obj1,obj2,obj3)
## then combining to get all permutations and applying your function
combn(seq_len(length(ll)),2,FUN = function(x){
  cor.test(ll[[x[1]]],ll[[x[2]]])
},simplify=FALSE)
```

where your objects are :

```
obj1 = 1:5
obj2 = 1:5
obj3 = 1:5
```

Comment: Thanks. I get an output that shows all the permutations ([1] 1 2; [2] 1 3; [3] 1 4; etc), but then how do I retrieve the functional output (in this case the correlation score for [1] 1 2)?

Comment: @user1038055 What is your functional output when you do `a <- cor.test(1,2)`?(in your question).

Comment: I'm not using correlation tests, but a more complicated script of my own for comparing matrices. But I'm not sure what that has to do with finding the output from your script? If I'm using your objects (obj1,obj2,obj3), I should get as output three correlation statistics (1,1,1), no?

Comment: @user1038055 amazing! If you use your own function why do you talk about `cor.test` that you confuse with `cor` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
objlist = c(obj1, obj2, obj3)

outlist = list()
len = length(objlist) 
for(i in 1:len) for (j in 1:len) if(i != j) {
    outlist[[length(outlist)+1]] = cor.test(objlist[[i]], objlist[[j]])
}
```

OR:

```
outlist = sapply(objlist, function(x) { sapply(objlist, function(y) cor.test(x,y)) } )
```

Comment: When I run the top script, I get the warning "not enough finite observations". If I make objlist a list (=list(obj1,obj2,obj3), then I get 9 results for correlation tests (which is too many) and all listing objlist[[i]] and objlist[[j]] as the data. Maybe I'm doing something wrong or is that your output too?

Comment: Objlist will have to be made. I have added ' if(i != j) ' so that the object is not correlated with itself. You will get 6 results now.